# JQuery Chosen plugin - appending options loaded with Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, select, jquery-plugins, jquery-chosen

Using a Standard Select with the Chosen plugin. In addition to the client-side matches, I need to display a list of additional items containing the search term, returned with ajax.

The ajax-chosen plugins I've found *replace* all results and don't seem to allow *appending* to the options already matched. This is the result I'm looking for:

```
    Optgroup A
       Option 1
       Option 2
     Optgroup B
       Option 3
       Option 4
     Options loaded from server
       Option loaded with ajax 1
       Option loaded with ajax 2
```

Comment: You can take a look on this plugin: https://github.com/meltingice/ajax-chosen

Comment: It replaces the options, I need them appended.

Comment: It allows appending. In your callback you should give each item "text" and "value" properties. If there is and _optgroup_ with and `item.title` _label_ it will append. I conclude that from relevant [source code](https://github.com/meltingice/ajax-chosen/blob/master/src/ajax-chosen.coffee#LC99) of the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

To update dynamically from ajax, I have appended to the original select:

```
$.each(data, function (index, element) {
    $('#inj-form-what-injury-type-detail')
    .append($("<option></option>")
    .attr("value", element.Type_No)
    .attr("selected", (element.isSelected) ? true : false)
    .text(element.Value));
});
```

Then, use liszt:updated to tell chosen that you have updated the select options

```
$('#inj-form-what-injury-type-detail').trigger("liszt:updated");
```

Not sure if this will work when using the search box, but it may provide a basis for your method.

[From the Chosen Documentation](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/)